# How to avoid to rebuild a lucene index with Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have stopped the db during a lucene indexing, then manually removed `index.db`, `index/` and `schema/` dir in `mydata.db` but every time I restart Neo4j it restarts the index building/repair. Is it possible to avoid it and back to a clean situation?

Comment: What is the purpose? For what?

Comment: I was creating an index with hundreds millions of nodes and it was taking too long. So I was changing the "indexing query" and batch it, but neo4j is keep on doing the old indexing.